# CORS issues in ionic requesting api hosted on localhost

Tags: api, ionic-framework, ionic3

My Ionic app run on `http://localhost:8100/` and I'm requesting `http://localhost:40410/api/myApi` for api.
I know it will get CORS issues , I tried by adding proxy setting in `ionic.config.json` like

```
"proxies": [
{
  "path": "/api",
  "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:40410/"
}
           ]
```

And when I `ionic serve` , I got this output on console `Proxy added:/api => https://localhost:44381/`  , but in app , I can't get any data from api.
This is what I got in chrome dev tools

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8100/api/myApi
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8100
```

this is my ts code ,

```
    this.http.get('/api/myApi').subscribe(
(data) => {
  console.log(data.json());
},(error) =>{
console.log(error);
}
   );
```

Comment: Why not use cors() in server side?

Comment: @Erez.S I too have a similar issue, can you elaborate on how to use cors() in server side?

Comment: run "npm install cors --save" and add this in app.js : app.use('*', cors());

Comment: @Erez.S app.js ? in ionic do you mean app.ts

Comment: cors issue is a server sided issue so using cors in ionic which is client sided is probably a mistake!

Comment: @Erez.S I tried `npm install cors --save` where should I add `app.js` as I do not have a www directory in my ionic project.
also I am running my app with ionic serve (ionic version is 4)

Answer (score -1):

You can run chrome with the following parameter to disable cors protection.
--disable-web-security

Comment: I can understand that by running chrome with disable web security or by using a cors anywhere plugin in chrome can solve the issue.

Comment: can you let me know if I run the same using ionic serve -c and then view it in my mobile how does it run ?